# refractor similar code snippet in ANT files

Tags: ant, mxmlc

i have the following code snippet in my ANT File which compiles my project to a swf file :

```
<target name="my target">
<mxmlc  file="${APPS_DIR}//@{appName}.mxml" 
    output="${DEPLOY_APPS_DIR}/@{appName}.swf" 
    actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8" 
    keep-generated-actionscript="false" 
    optimize="true" 
    debug="${DEBUG_TF}" 
    locale="en_US"
    static-rsls="false"
    static-link-runtime-shared-libraries="false"
    verify-digests="false"> 
<!-- BEGIN code A -->
...
...
...
<!-- END code A -->
</mxmlc>
</target>
```

As i have much files that use the **code A** in similar way, I want to create a separable file which contains this code.

But, how can I call it from the main ant file ?

Comment: Your `Code A` is inside a `<mxmlc>` task. Does the task it self could be reused? And, what does `Code A` contain? Most tasks that supports nested elements accept only a small set of tasks and types. For example, one task may only accept `<fileset>` as its nested element. So I am not sure if `<macrodef>` could do this.

Comment: I don't think it would work, but you can still check it out: https://gist.github.com/2957900

Comment: thank you for your help but i found the solution for it. you will find it in the next comment.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and accept it for those who may come there by searching in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Answered and asked by myself at the same time. I was found it [here](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#xml-entity-include).

You can use XML's way of including external files and let the parser do the job for Ant:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE project [
       <!ENTITY common SYSTEM "common.xml">
]>
<project name="test" default="test" basedir=".">
  <target name="setup">
    ...
  </target>
  &common;
  ...   
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`import`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html). It will do the same as the [entity include,](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#xml-entity-include) but it will also give you the ability to overriding targets and provides special properties like the path to the imported ant file. From the `import` docs:

> So if I import for example a docsbuild.xml file named builddocs, I can get its path as ant.file.builddocs, similarly to the ant.file property of the main buildfile.

*Updated* (because I didn't read the orignal question properly)

Within your imported file, create a [`presetdef`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/presetdef.html) like the following

```
<presetdef name="mxmlc" uri="com.chercheinfo">
   <mxmlc> 
<!-- BEGIN code A -->
...
...
...
<!-- END code A -->
   </mxmlc>
</presetdef>
```

Then you can change your target to:

```
<target name="my target">
    <kaissun:mxmlc  file="${APPS_DIR}//@{appName}.mxml" 
        output="${DEPLOY_APPS_DIR}/@{appName}.swf" 
        actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8" 
        keep-generated-actionscript="false" 
        optimize="true" 
        debug="${DEBUG_TF}" 
        locale="en_US"
        static-rsls="false"
        static-link-runtime-shared-libraries="false"
        verify-digests="false"> 
    </kaissun:mxmlc>
</target>
```

(you will need to add the following attribute `xmlns:kaissun="com.chercheinfo"` to your `project` element to bind `kaissun` to `com.chercheinfo`)

You can use `presetdef` to preset common attributes as well. E.g.,

```
<presetdef name="mxmlc" uri="com.chercheinfo">
   <mxmlc actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8"
       keep-generated-actionscript="false"
       optimize="true"
       locale="en_US"
       static-rsls="false"
       static-link-runtime-shared-libraries="false"
       verify-digests="false"> 
<!-- BEGIN code A -->
...
...
...
<!-- END code A -->
   </mxmlc>
</presetdef>
```

would allow you to shrink your target to

```
<target name="my target">
    <kaissun:mxmlc  file="${APPS_DIR}//@{appName}.mxml" 
        output="${DEPLOY_APPS_DIR}/@{appName}.swf" 
        debug="${DEBUG_TF}"> 
    </kaissun:mxmlc>
</target>
```

:D

Comment: +1 ! Cool for the use of my pseudo and the site ;) it is a good solution even it is more complicated, just because contains my pseudo :) thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @kaissun everyone loves a personal touch. :)